# print current date in java

Tags: java, time

I want to print current date and time in java..This is the code I am trying from a java tutorial:

```
import java.util.*;
  
public class Date {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       // Instantiate a Date object
       Date date = new Date();
        
       // display time and date using toString()
       System.out.println(date.toString());
   }
}
```

It compiles fine. But the output given is:

> Date@15db9742

While i am expecting a output like this:

> Mon May 04 09:51:52 CDT 2009

What is wrong with the code?

EDIT:
I tried to rename the class.. The editted code:

```
import java.util.*;
  
public class DateDemo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       // Instantiate a Date object
       Date d = new Date();
        
       // display time and date using toString()
       System.out.println(d.toString());
   }
}
```

This is how I compiled the code and ran:

> sou@sou-linux:~/Desktop/java$ javac DateDemo.java
>
> sou@sou-linux:~/Desktop/java$ java DateDemo

The output is:

> Date@15db9742

Comment: which version of java have you got?

Comment: rename your class, you are now instantiating the class itself

Comment: Tried renaming my class. The output is still not I desired..

Comment: @rick112358 Did the output change? Did you build clean?

Comment: no the output didn't change.. I edited the post with the new code and output

Comment: delete `Date.java` and `Date.class` in your current folder! They're also in the default package so you're getting them from your old `Date`.

Comment: @rick112358: You probably have the compiled bytecode of the old class (Date.class) still somewhere on your classpath. Simply renaming the source file and compile it again won't delete the result of the previous compilation.

Comment: delete the Date.class from bin created from your previous code

Comment: Deleting the Date.class solved the issue.. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your class is a custom class that is producing the output given by `Object.toString`. Rename the class to something else other than `Date` so that `java.util.Date` is correctly imported

Comment: Along with renaming the class, he will also need to delete previous written Date.java and Date.class before recompiling the new code to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 14):

You are getting the default `toString()` from `Object` because you created your own class named `Date` which is hiding the imported `Date` from `java.util.`. You can rename your class or you can use the canonical name [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) like

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Output here is

```
Mon Nov 03 10:57:45 EST 2014
```

Answer (score 12):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    //get current date time with Date()
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

    //get current date time with Calendar()
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename your class from Date to something else .. The following then works just as expected:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class ImplClass
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Date date = new Date();

       // display time and date using toString()
       System.out.println(date.toString());
   }

}
```

The output is in the desired format

```
Mon Nov 03 09:49:57 CST 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Dte {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }
}
```

Change the class name `Date` to `Dte` or some thing and the code will work properly.

The output is : `Mon Nov 03 21:27:15 IST 2014`

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the toString() method, because:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

*Quote from docs.oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).*

The Date class is designed to use like everyone else has answered. Just wanted to explain/give you a reference to why.

Comment: java.util.Date class overrides toString() method of Object class to print the date in following format: dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy The real reason of 'why?' is that his Date object is not of java.util.Date class but his own Date class.

Answer (score 2):

Already, the root cause has been pointed out and the resolution has been suggested in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717832/10819573). This answer is to introduce the modern Date-Time API to future visitors.

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2021-07-03T14:08:02.594203Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/UJYEDV)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

**Note:** In case you have got an object of `java.util.Date`, you can convert it to `Instant` as shown below:

```
Date date = new Date(); // A sample date
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
```

### How to display the current Date-Time in a particular timezone:

Use [`ZonedDateTime#now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now--) or [`ZonedDateTime#now(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) to display the current Date-Time in a particular timezone.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The current date-time in the JVM's timezone
        ZonedDateTime zdtDefaultTz = ZonedDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(zdtDefaultTz);

        // The current date-time in a specific timezone
        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2021-07-03T15:19:48.007549+01:00[Europe/London]
2021-07-03T10:19:48.010048-04:00[America/New_York]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Mo409S)

### How to display the current Date-Time in a particular timezone if you have got an instance of `java.util.Date` or `Instant`:

Convert `Instant` to `ZonedDateTime` representing Date-Time in the required timezone e.g.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now(); // new Date().toInstant()

        ZonedDateTime zdtDefaultTz = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdtDefaultTz);

        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdtUtc);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-07-03T15:24:23.716050+01:00[Europe/London]
2021-07-03T10:24:23.716050-04:00[America/New_York]
2021-07-03T14:24:23.716050Z[Etc/UTC]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/5oeehK)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your class name is Date so

```
Date date = new Date();
```

will create an object of your class and when you call `date.toString()` it will be the default `Object.toString()` method.
So if you have to use the `java.util.Date` class, rename your `Date` class to something else

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the code as simple as ::

```
import java.util.*;
public class Today{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("System Date :: ");
    System.out.println(new Date());
  }
}
```

As well as change the class name to today or something else but not Date as it is a keyword