# What is the easiest way to get the current date in Basic ISO 8601 format, YYYYMMDD?

Tags: java

And how to print it as a string.

I tried this but I get the date in (YYYMMMMDDD HHSSMM) format:

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
```

What is the easiest way to get the current date in [Basic ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (***YYYYMMDD***) format?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [print current date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717733/print-current-date-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current date/time in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This does the trick but may not be the easiest:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you commenting that under every answer here but I don't see your answer yet. Mind to share?

Comment: When `LocalDateTime` from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is asked about, please don’t introduce the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Today we have so much better in java.time and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: If you also prefer to specify the Java class files to import, we can use the following:
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Comment: Best answer for API < 26

Comment: Just a small comment: using import * is not recommended - import only what you need.

Answer (score 38):

is that what you are looking for?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().format(formatter));
```

Comment: More details here http://www.journaldev.com/2800/java-8-date-time-api-example-tutorial-localdate-instant-localdatetime-parse-and-format

Comment: This, or just [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE) instead of the formatter creation.

Comment: Uppercase `YYYY` is wrong, you need lowercase `yyyy` for year of era or `uuuu` for (signed) year.

Comment: I get an error for `LocalDate.now().format(formatter)` as `.format()` is not supported.

Comment: @ShaiAlon what error you are getting and which java version are you using?

Answer (score 10):

```
DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE.format(LocalDate.now());
```

Comment: There is a type mismatch there: `Type mismatch Can't assign org.joda.time.LocalDate to java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor`

Answer (score 8):

This is a very old question but gets me every time.  There is a much simpler way now in one line:

```
String now = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
System.out.println(now);
```

outputs:  2020-07-09

Answer (score 4):

Just use: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
// Create an instance of SimpleDateFormat used for formatting 
// the string representation of date (month/day/year)
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// Get the date today using Calendar object.
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
// Using DateFormat format method we can create a string 
// representation of a date with the defined format.
String reportDate = df.format(today);

// Print what date is today!
System.out.println("Report Date: " + reportDate);
```

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/

Comment: In 2015, I would like to see the default answer using the `java.time` package, and NOT the obsolete `Date` class and friends.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use the built-in formatter.

```
LocalDate.now().format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE )
```

> 20240123

## `LocalDate`

Understand that determining today's date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

Capture the current date using the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
```

Better to specify the desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

For the [“Basic” version of ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (YYYYMMDD), use [the predefined constant formatter object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
String output = today.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```