# How to get the time that it took to type a sentence in Java

Tags: java, date, time, java.util.date, elapsedtime

I have a kind of complex problem that I hope I can get some help on.
My teacher has asked for a homework question that we find how long it took us to type a sentence "Hello World!" and print it out in milliseconds using the Date class while also checking if it is correct.
This is what I have so far

```
import java.util.*;
public class Date 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner hello = new Scanner (System.in);
    Date d1 = new Date();
    System.out.println("Your job is to type the sentence \"Hello World!\" as fast as you can.");
    System.out.println("When you are ready, press enter, type the sentence, and press enter again.");
    System.out.println("");
    String sen = hello.nextLine();
    if(sen == "Hello World!")
    {
        System.out.println(d1.getTime());
    }
    if (sen != "Hello World!")
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
    }
}
}
```

I looked some stuff up and I'm trying to use the getTime method, but it just doesn't let me use it.

My main idea is to use getTime to check how long it took the user to input the sentence, but I am just not at all sure how to do that.

Comment: Aside from your question, don't use `==` to compare `sen` to `"Hello World!"`. You need to use `sen.equals("Hello World!")`.

Comment: Teachers who ask  their students to use the `Date` class deserve to be sacked. That class was poorly designed, which is why it got replaced with [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) nearly 7 years ago.

Comment: @AJ Mosley, welcome to SO, please post your questions without your personal story, also, share with us what your findings are to solve the problem.

Comment: *I'm trying to use the getTime method, but it just doesn't let me use it.* Please post the code line where you try that along with the error message that you get. It’s the only way we can help you with that. And yes, if you’re to use `Date` as your teacher says, then `getTime()` is the method to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print current date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717733/print-current-date-in-java). I know the title doesn’t sound the same, but please study the contents of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

## Count nanoseconds with `System.nanoTime`

I think you're close, but the method needs some improvement.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner hello = new Scanner(System.in);
    // starting time
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Your job is to type the sentence \"Hello World!\" as fast as you can.");
    System.out.println("When you are ready, press enter, type the sentence, and press enter again.\n");
    String sen = hello.nextLine();
    while (!sen.equals("Hello World!")) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
        sen = hello.nextLine();
    }
    // end time
    long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println("It took you "elapsedTime"ns to type Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Tip: `Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start ).toString()`

Comment: Yes, that would be better option, I just wanted to point out possible solution, that he could understand. Anyways, thank you for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner hello = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Your job is to type the sentence \"Hello World!\" as fast as you can.");
        System.out.println("When you are ready, press enter, type the sentence, and press enter again.");
        System.out.println("");
        long start = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        String sen = hello.nextLine();
        if (sen.equals("Hello World!")) {
            System.out.println("You took " + (Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - start) + " milliseconds");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Your job is to type the sentence "Hello World!" as fast as you can.
When you are ready, press enter, type the sentence, and press enter again.

Hello World!
You took 4711 milliseconds
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Also, compare strings by using [`String#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) instead of `==`.

### If at all you need to use `java.util.Date`:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner hello = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Your job is to type the sentence \"Hello World!\" as fast as you can.");
        System.out.println("When you are ready, press enter, type the sentence, and press enter again.");
        System.out.println("");
        Date date = new Date();
        long start = date.getTime();
        String sen = hello.nextLine();
        if (sen.equals("Hello World!")) {
            date = new Date();
            long end = date.getTime();
            System.out.println("You took " + (end - start) + " milliseconds");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct that it’s better to use `System.nanotime()` or `Instant` (so your teacher is wrong). In any case, since you have to use `Date`, I will try to explain what went wrong when you tried to use the `getTime` method. Because you are correct: if you’re using the old and poorly designed `Date` class, then use its `getTime` method.

You have called your own class `Date` too. So there are two classes with the same class name in play here, which gives rise to the trouble. When you do this:

```
    Date d1 = new Date();
```

— then you are creating an instance of your own `Date` class, not of the `java.util.Date` class that your teacher (probably) meant. And when next you try for example (which you didn’t show us in your question, but you should):

```
    long time = d1.getTime();
```

— then Java sees that your own `Date` class hasn’t got a `getTime` method and issues an error message.

**TL;DR** The solution is to call your own class something else than `Date`.

PS There are ways to handle two classes with the same name, but it’s never quite as easy to read and I don’t recommend it here.